tailwind css not working on production in vercel
I made portfolio website using nextjs
my website is working fine in localhost but on production components where i used tailwind css are spreading or are not intact.
for e.g here is my code for nav bar where i used tailwind css
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Bars3Icon } from "@heroicons/react/16/solid";
import React from "react";

interface NavLinkProps {
    onClick: () => void;
    children: React.ReactNode; // Explicitly define the children prop
}

interface Props {
    openNav: () => void;
}

const Nav: React.FC<Props> = ({ openNav }) => {
    const router = useRouter(); // useRouter hook to access router information

    // Function to handle smooth scrolling to the anchor
    const scrollToSection = (id: string): void => {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="w-full fixed z-50 top-0 h-[12vh] bg-[#141c27] shadow-md">
            <div className="flex justify-between w-[85%] mx-auto h-[100%] items-center">
                <h1 className="flex-[0.6] cursor-pointer text-[30px] text-white font-bold">
                    SHUBHAM
                    <span className="text-yellow-300"> BHATT</span>
                </h1>
                <div className="flex space-x-6">

                    <NavLink onClick={() => scrollToSection("home")}>HOME</NavLink>
                    <NavLink onClick={() => scrollToSection("about")}>ABOUT</NavLink>
                    <NavLink onClick={() => scrollToSection("projects")}>PROJECTS</NavLink>
                    <NavLink onClick={() => scrollToSection("skills")}>SKILLS</NavLink>
                    <NavLink onClick={() => scrollToSection("contact")}>CONTACT</NavLink>
                </div>
                <div onClick={openNav}>
                    <Bars3Icon className="w-[2rem] md:hidden h-[2rem] cursor-pointer text-yellow-300" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const NavLink: React.FC<NavLinkProps> = ({ onClick, children }) => {
    return (
        <span className="nav-link text-white" onClick={onClick}>
            {children}
        </span>
    );
};

export default Nav;

now here is my education tab, where i used both styled component and tailwind css
style component is intact on production but i used tailwind in heading, it is not showing in production
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  Timeline,
  TimelineItem,
  TimelineSeparator,
  TimelineConnector,
  TimelineDot,
} from "@mui/lab";

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: #121121;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
  @media (max-width: 960px) {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f0e68c;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
`;

const TimelineSection = styled.div`
  width: 60%;
  @media (max-width: 660px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const EducationCard = styled.div`
  background-color: #121121;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Changed to column */
  align-items: flex-start; /* Changed to flex-start */
  gap: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  &:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  outline: 2px solid #854CE6;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    padding; 10px;
}
`;

const Image = styled.img`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 8px; /* Changed border-radius */
  margin-right: 20px; /* Added margin-right */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  color: #fff; /* Changed text color */
`;

const School = styled.h3`
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0; /* Removed margin */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
`;

const Date = styled.p`
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0; /* Removed margin */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;

const Grade = styled.p`
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0; /* Removed margin */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;

const Degree = styled.p`
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0; /* Removed margin */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;

const Description = styled.p`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: grey;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;

const EducationPage: React.FC = () => {
  const education = [
    {
      id: 0,
      img: "https://www.namastedehradun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Graphic_Era_Hill_University_Logo-300x300.png",
      school: "Graphic Era Hill University, Dehradun",
      date: "Sept 2021 - July 2025",
      grade: "8.17 CGPA",
      desc: "I am currently pursuing a Bachelor's degree in Computer Science and Engineering at Graphic Era Hill University Dehradun Uttarakhand. I am currently in 3rd year. I have taken courses in Data Structures, Algorithms, Object-Oriented Programming, Database Management Systems, Operating Systems, and Computer Networks, among others.",
      degree:
        "Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science and Engineering",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      img: "/images/aps.png",
      school: "Genl BC Joshi Army Public School Pithoragarh",
      date: "Apr 2019 - Apr 2020",
      grade: "91.6%",
      desc: "I completed my class 12 from General BC Joshi Army Public School Pithoragarh with subjects Physics, Chemistry, Maths and Computer Science",
      degree: "CBSE(XII), Science with Computer",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      img: "/images/dbs.jpeg",
      school: "Don Bosco Sr Sec School Pithoragarh",
      date: "Apr 2017 - Apr 2018",
      grade: "82.5%",
      desc: "I completed my class 10 education at Don Bosco Sr Sec School Pithoragarh, where I studied Science, Social Science, Mathematics, English, Hindi and Computer Science",
      degree: "CBSE(X), Science with Computer",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Container id="education">
      <h1 className="heading">
        EDU<span className="text-yellow-400">CATION</span>
      </h1>
      <Wrapper>
        <TimelineSection>
          <Timeline>
            {education.map((edu, index) => (
              <TimelineItem key={edu.id}>
                <EducationCard>
                  <Image src={edu.img} alt={edu.school} />
                  <Content>
                    <School>{edu.school}</School>
                    <Degree>{edu.degree}</Degree>
                    <Date>{edu.date}</Date>
                    <Grade>{edu.grade}</Grade>
                    <Description>{edu.desc}</Description>
                  </Content>
                </EducationCard>
                {index !== education.length && (
                  <TimelineSeparator>
                    <TimelineDot
                      variant="outlined"
                      color="secondary"
                      sx={{ position: "relative", top: "-10px", left: "15px" }}
                    />
                    <TimelineConnector
                      style={{
                        background: "#854CE6",
                        marginLeft: "20px",
                        marginTop: "-10px",
                        marginBottom: "30px",
                      }}
                    />
                  </TimelineSeparator>
                )}
              </TimelineItem>
            ))}
          </Timeline>
        </TimelineSection>
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default EducationPage;

my global css
my tailwind config
what can be the solution??
Link to github repo(for full code) - https://github.com/shubhambhatt037/my-portfolio
link to production site - https://my-portfolio-chi-liart-87.vercel.app/
i hope, I can get some help
Thank You

What I would try first:
#1:
Your project structure contains:
•/
├── Components/ <-- uppercase
├── ...
├── ...

With a capital C in components... while in your tailwind.config.ts:
content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", // <-- lowercase
 
    // ...
  ],


#2:
Your globals.css:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap'); // <-- should come after tailwind

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


Notes
Nextjs uses server-side rendering, so styled-components will load lazily.

npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components

Add a .babelrc file in your root directory:
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}

I believe you also might need to add this to your next config:
compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
},

(but that might seemingly be only with the App router, and you're using pages)

References:

Tailwindcss & Styled
Components
Styling: CSS-in-JS | Next.js
Server-side Rendering


